# HTML5 Input types (date, week, ...) all selectable not only arrow

Tags: html, input

Is it possible to make the whole `input type=date` selectable?

I can only select the date when I click the small arrow on the right. It should be like the jQuery datepicker where I can click wherever I want on the div or input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tdL1gz4/). It uses Javascript, can't achieve without it as far as I'm concerned.

HTML:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
 $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );**strong text**
```

Source [JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: When OP said it should be like jQuery I don't think they meant they actually wanted to use jQuery. They want to make the `<input type=date />` tag act like it.

Comment: Exactly. Sorry mate but I want to make the whole input date clickable to show the calendar

Comment: My bad folks :/